# How after pressing "Enter" at the end of the text that is in the form field add ", " and the cursor did not move to the next line?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How after pressing "Enter" at the end of the text that is in the form field add ", " and the cursor did not move to the next line?
Logics:
- The user enters "Text_1";
- The user presses "Enter";
- The code adds ", ";
- Result in the form field - "Text_1, ";
- The user enters "Text_2";
- The user presses "Enter";
- The code adds ", ";
- Result in the form field - "Text_1, Text_2, ";

```
Private Sub Field1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
        If KeyCode = 13 Then  
                    Me.Field1.Text = Me.Field1.Text & ", "                     
                    Me.Field1.SelStart = Len(Me.Field1.Text)             
         End If ' KeyCode
End Sub
```

I try to do, but I can't.
Now the cursor after pressing "Enter" moves to the next line.
[image]

How to make the cursor remain on the same line with the text?
[image]

**Update_1**
How to make a space after the comma?
[image]

My solution does not leave a space after the comma after pressing "Enter".
[image]

**Update_2**
Database file - [link](https://dropmefiles.com/Tqw01)

Comment: "I try to do, but I can't" - is that a complete sentence? What is the problem exactly? If you want to "swallow" the ENTER keypress, you can set the `KeyCode` to `0` before the handler returns.

Comment: If you're using comma delimited lists in Access, you might want to review your level of database normalization.  It sounds like you're trying to put what should be multiple records into a single field.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Updated question. If I could not correctly formulate, I will wait for your additional questions.

Comment: @Comintern Updated question. If I could not correctly formulate, I will wait for your additional questions.

Comment: See @MathieuGuindon's first comment.  Just eat the keypress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to "swallow" the keypress. You can do that by setting the `KeyCode` to `0` - notice it's *implicitly* being passed `ByRef` (parameters are passed by reference in VBA, unless specified otherwise), so by changing the value in the handler (which is invoked before the keypress lands into the textbox), the event source will see that value as `0`.

```
Private Sub Field1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then  
        Me.Field1.Text = Me.Field1.Text & ", "                     
        Me.Field1.SelStart = Len(Me.Field1.Text)             
        KeyCode = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How to make a space after the comma?

Comment: The space should be there, it's concatenated in with the comma

Comment: Updated question. If I understand you correctly, then you say that there is a gap in the code.
It ", ". But when I press "Enter" the cursor remains immediately after the comma.
Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @eusataf and you're using exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54486380/1188513) code?

Comment: Is the textbox bound to a text field on a table? If so, it may be inheriting the trimming behavior of a variable-length field.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon Updated the question.
Attached data file.

Comment: @this Updated the question.
Attached data file. `If so, it may be inheriting the trimming behavior of a variable-length field.` - How to solve this problem?

Comment: @eusataf IMO it's not a problem, and the whitespace is extraneous wasted storage anyway. Consider [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485938/how-after-pressing-enter-at-the-end-of-the-text-that-is-in-the-form-field-add/54486380?noredirect=1#comment95778769_54485938).

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon Sorry, I do not understand what I have to do.
I'm just starting to learn VBA.
I want to use the form field so that the user can enter filter criteria there, separated by a comma.
After the user types the criteria, the form will be filtered.
I have deleted the link field with the table.
The field where the user enters the criteria for the filter is not associated with the table.

If it's not difficult for you, could you describe in more detail what I should do.